# Json to c# get child nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am getting a response from a API that returns the following json:

```
[
  {
   "input_index":0,
   "candidate_index":0,
   "components":,
      {
       "child1":"sam",
       "child2":"tom",
      }
  }
 ]
```

i need to get the results of child1 and child2 using c# and json.net.

Comment: Great - that sounds reasonably simple... so what have you tried so far? Are you trying to deserialize to a class, or using LINQ to JSON? (`JObject.Parse` etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fairly straightforward. Just parse the JSON, then get the child items from the `components` object of the array's first index:

```
var obj = JArray.Parse(json);
string child1 = (string)obj[0]["components"]["child1"];
string child2 = (string)obj[0]["components"]["child2"];
```

Comment: That looks like NewtonSoft, not modern build-in

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin The question was asking about how to do it using Newtonsoft (json.net)