# Need all the unique Keys name from Json string

Tags: c#, json.net

I have following sample json string in C#

```
{
    "AccountNumberGenerationRequest": {
        "BranchNumber": 8034,
        "AccountType": "041"
    },
    "CreateDepositAccountRequest": {
        "AccountNumber": "9999999999",
        "BranchNumber": 8034,
        "AccountType": 41,
        "WithholdingIndicator": "4"
    },
    "AccountNameAddressRequest": {
        "AccountNumber": "9999999999",
        "NameAndAddressType": 1,
    },
    "CustomerAccountRelationshipRequest": {
        "CustomerNumber1": "58008",
        "Customer1ToAccountRelationshipCode": "000"
    },
    "UpdatePartialInformationRequest": {
        "AccountNumber": "9999999999",
        "PartialInformationList": [{
            "KeywordCode": "FDWTHE",
            "KeywordValue": "1"
        }]
    },
    "RequestUUID": "557d5442-8a28-4dab-b191-fe1596ddf2b8"
}
```

And want to read all the unique keys that has end values. Like below

```
["BranchNumber","AccountType","AccountNumber","BranchNumber","AccountType","WithholdingIndicator","AccountNumber","NameAndAddressType","CustomerNumber1","Customer1ToAccountRelationshipCode","KeywordCode","KeywordValue","RequestUUID"]
```

I am using following code

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

        var json=  JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, jsonSerializerSettings));

        IList<string> keys = json.Properties().Select(c=> c.Name).ToList();

        foreach(string key in keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
```

But getting only

```
AccountNumberGenerationRequest
AccountNumberGenerationRequest
AccountNameAddressRequest
AccountNameAddressRequest
UpdatePartialInformationRequest
RequestUUID
```

How Can I get this in C#. This is not hardcoded Json. It can be any json.

Comment: Can you share whatever code you have written for this and explain what issue you are facing in that ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I need the code to get this. I have not written any code.

Comment: You are only looking at parent items, you could try to iterate over the child items.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680492/json-to-c-sharp-get-child-nodes

Comment: @AnyMoose. I do not know the keys of Json. This is dynamic. I gave just sample json.

Comment: Deserialize to a Dictionary and look at the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to flatten the object and filter accordingly:

```
var uniqueKeys = json.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(x => x.Value is JValue)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: You don't need to make your own `Flatten()` extension method; you could just use the built-in [`Descendants()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_Extensions_Descendants__1.htm) extension method instead.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/szIubI